# ido-mode binding masked by global-set-key

Tags: emacs, elisp

stackoverflow! In the past few days I was trying to customize my emacs a little bit and I faced the problem that I don't know how to approach.

What I'm trying to do is to define a global keybinding and an ido-mode keybinding that would use the same keys to do different things.

Ido-mode keybinding is defined this way:

```
(defun ido-my-keys ()
  "Add my keybindings for ido."
  (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-<return>") 
    'ido-invoke-in-vertical-split)
  )

(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)
```

And it works fine until I place the following line in my .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-<return>") 'insert-newline-and-indent)
```

With this line present M-return invokes insert-newline-and-indent even from ido-switch-buffer. Interestingly, when I use global-set-key interactively (i.e. not from init-file but from M-x invocation), everything works as expected.

Thanks for your help. Sorry for my english.

---

The problem turned out to be in ergoemacs-mode that I had turned on. This mode defines an advice for global-set-key that causes this effect.

I solved the problem by moving the global-set-key call above the ergoemacs initialization. Not the best solution, but a simple one.

Comment: I cant reproduce this. BTW `ido-invoke-in-vertical-split` is not inbuilt function I had to google for it. https://gist.github.com/493269

Comment: I'm sorry for such obscurity. Anyway, this function doesn't seem to be related to the problem: changing it to something else (e.g. ido-exit-minibuffer) doesn't change the effect.

Comment: Which version of Emacs are you using? I can't reproduce this problem either (in Emacs 24.0.94).

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. That sounds like something which could easily bite other ErgoEmacs users. What you now need to do is write the solution as an answer to your question (including any details you think would help other people with the same problem), and then accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I was about to do so, but the site didn't allow me to post an answer to my own question yesterday. Now, when I wrote the answer, the site doesn't allow me to accept it as the correct one. I'll have to wait for another two days to accept it. Weird :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by ergoemacs-keybindings package, or, to be more specific, by ergoemacs-mode.el

This package defines an advice for global-set-key that, in fact, replaces it with its own ergoemacs-global-set-key. But since ergoemacs is a minor mode, its keymap has higher precedence than the global map, thus overriding keybinding of ido minor mode.

I see three solutions to that problem:

1. Comment-out advice in ergoemacs-mode.el.
2. Use global-set-key BEFORE you turn on ergoemacs-mode.
3. Wait for the ergoemacs author to fix the bug ;)