# ido-completion-map keys not working when ergoemacs is enable

Tags: emacs, ido, ergoemacs

When using ergo emacs, for some reason M-l and M-j (forward-char and backward-char respectively) don't work properly in the minibuffer (with ido mode).

I've tried setting the ido-completion-map with the following:

```
(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-k") 'ido-next-match)
    (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-i") 'ido-prev-match)
    (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-l") 'ido-next-match)
    (define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "M-j") 'ido-prev-match)))
```

but these don't seem to stick.

I seem to be having a similar problem to this person: [ido-mode binding masked by global-set-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877557/ido-mode-binding-masked-by-global-set-key) but none of the solutions seems to work for me

Any help would be very appreciated

Kind regards
Nimai

Answer (score 0):

Although the instructions at the outset of `ido.el` suggest using:

```
;; Customization
;; -------------
;;
;; Customize the Ido group to change the Ido functionality.
;;
;; To modify the keybindings, use the ido-setup-hook.  For example:
;;(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)
;;
;;(defun ido-my-keys ()
;;  "Add my keybindings for ido."
;;  (define-key ido-completion-map " " 'ido-next-match)
;;  )
```

I recently found that using the `ido-common-completion-map` had better luck when using a frame-switch function -- the original poster can substitute his / her own preferred keyboard shortcuts instead of `m-tab` and/or `m-S-tab`:

```
(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)

(defun ido-my-keys ()
  "Add my keybindings for ido."
  (define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<M-tab>") 'ido-next-match)
  (define-key ido-common-completion-map (kbd "<M-S-tab>") 'ido-prev-match) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I have met the save problem, i'm using Emacs 24.4 with ergoemacs-mode-5.14.7.3 (i don't use the latest version of ergoemacs because it has the speed issue. See: [github issue](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/issues/315)). After a lot of searching, i finally find this [github commit](https://github.com/ergoemacs/ergoemacs-mode/commit/aef22ba16b8469ff33b09caf44ff3b486f624129), and get it work by adding below code to my emacs init file:

after enable ergoemacs-mode:

```
(when ido-mode
  (global-set-key [remap ido-magic-forward-char] 'ido-next-match)
  (global-set-key [remap ido-magic-backward-char] 'ido-prev-match))
```

Hope it helps, thanks!